# find different string in one row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, find, match

I want to return join from this following text that contains `find = ['gold', 'mining', 'silver, 'steel']` but turns out it just prints the first one that appears.

one of the row in **output.csv**

```
desc
"The **2014 Orkney earthquake** occurred at 12:22:33 SAST on 5 August, with the
epicentre near Orkney, a gold mining town in the Klerksdorp district in the
North West province of South Africa. The shock was assigned a magnitude of 5.5
on the Richter scale by the Council for Geoscience (CGS) in South Africa,
making it the biggest earthquake in South Africa since the 1969 Tulbagh
earthquake, which had a magnitude of 6.3 on the Richter scale. The United
States Geological Survey (USGS) estimated a focal depth of 5.0 km (3.1 mi).
The CGS reported 84 aftershocks on 5 August and 31 aftershocks on 6 August,
with a magnitude of 1.0 to 3.8 on the Richter scale. According to the CGS, the
earthquake is the biggest mining-related earthquake in South African history."
```

**output:** gold

**expected output:** gold, mining

**here is what I have done**

```
reader = pd.read_csv('output.csv', chunksize=1000)
    find = ['gold','mining','silver','steel']
    for chunk in reader:
        chunk.columns = ['desc']
        def process(x):
            for s in find:
                if s in x['desc']:
                    print('', s)
                    return s
            return ''
        chunk['place'] = chunk.apply(lambda x: (process(x)), axis=1)
        chunk = chunk.drop(chunk[chunk['place'] == ''].index).reset_index(drop=True)
        print(chunk)
```

How to join the result?

**EDIT**

```
def preprocess_patetnt(name):
    reader = pd.read_csv('output.csv', chunksize=1000)
    sname = sorted(name, key=len, reverse=True)
    for chunk in reader:
        chunk.columns = ['row', 'desc']
        chunk['place'] = chunk["desc"].str.findall("|".join(sname)).apply(set)
        chunk = chunk.drop(chunk[chunk['place'] == ''].index).reset_index(drop=True)
        print(chunk)

place = pd.read_csv('country.csv', chunksize=13000000, error_bad_lines=False)
for chunk in place:
    chunk.columns = ['name']
    preprocess_patetnt(chunk["name"])
```

from country.csv is a list of name country like following:
[country.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRj33.png)

and here is output.csv
[output.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXKWM.png)

But it gives me this error: `re.error: bad character range á-K at position 77230`

Comment: Do you mean `chunk["desc"].str.findall("|".join(find))`?

Comment: @HenryYik Many thanks! That's what I want, but what if I want it to print just one like in this case:  'The **Beaulieu Mine** was a post-World War II gold mining operation near
Yellowknife, Northwest Territories. It entered production in October 1947 but
by the end of November only 7 troy ounces (220 g) of rough gold were
recovered. Additional gold was recovered during 1948 but altogether the mine
recovered only 30 troy ounces (930 g) of fine gold. The operation folded in
chaos and bankruptcy.'  it turns out `gold, mining, gold, gold, gold` what if I want it print just `gold, mining`

Comment: You can apply the column to a `set`, i.e. `chunk["desc"].str.findall("|".join(find)).apply(set)`.

Comment: Great! It's perfect. I want to ask one more what if in `find` array there is a unicode string like `Pleta del Maià, L’Hortó, Vračkovice` it gives me error: `re.error: bad character range á-K at position 77230`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error you mentioned.

Comment: @HenryYik I already edit my question, hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Your `process` function returns as soon as it gets the first hit. Insted, you should store all your hits in a string and return it. Use list comprehension for these kind of loops 
 and `str.join(iterable)` method to join the list to a string (I'm guessing here that `sname` is actually `find`).

```
reader = pd.read_csv('output.csv', chunksize=1000)
    find = ['gold','mining','silver','steel']
    for chunk in reader:
        chunk.columns = ['desc']
        def process(x):
            return ','.join([s for s in find if s in x['desc']])
        chunk['place'] = chunk.apply(lambda x: (process(x)), axis=1)
        chunk = chunk.drop(chunk[chunk['place'] == ''].index).reset_index(drop=True)
        print(chunk)
```

happy coding!

Comment: Yeah I forgot to edit this line, sname is `find`. Thanks for your help but it gives me this error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements`